# Auto Hot Key.. Button Holding?

Tags: autohotkey

My brain is borderline flat and I'm having no luck understanding what Up and Down mean. I only want the hotkey to hold left click for whatever amount of time. If anyone could provide the code used for that and maybe a short explanation of how Up and Down work (r/explainlikeim5) that would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Down=pressed. Up=released. Just like your keyboard. You push the key down and let it come back up. Put your pointing finger on the letter A on your keyboard. Push it down until it stops - that's down. Take your finger of the key. That's up. There you go.

Comment: Hi @DevEc What have you tried?  What was the result?  Pressing or holding keys is something autohotkey does quite well.  Did you look at the help?  Try the Quick Reference and Tutorial for beginners.  What you want is describe early on, maybe 5 minutes of reading.  Good luck, and let us know how you make out. . .

Answer (score 0):

```
$Lbutton:: ;when you push left mouse button(Can be changed)
Sendinput, {LButton down} ; holds left mouse button down
Sleep, 1000 ; delay in miliseconds(1 second delay)
Sendinput, {LButton up} ; releases left mouse button
Return
```

There you go sir.